# Chrome 84+: A website wants to open this application: Handlers

Tags: google-chrome, handler

I had the following fixes, which opened the needed application in Chrome without confirmation each time.  They worked well until the update of **Version 84.0.4147.89 (Official Build) (64-bit)**.

Fix 1:

```
In C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences
"protocol_handler":{"excluded_schemes":{"neededApp":false}}
```

Fix 2:

```
In Regedit: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome
Create DWORD ExternalProtocolDialogShowAlwaysOpenCheckbox =1
```

Any idea what changed or how to fix that issue for the new version?  It doesn't happen with all apps.

Comment: Did u found any solution?

Comment: @user998405 No.  Are you having the same issue?

Comment: Same no solution. I asked my client change to other browser or use older chrome version

Comment: You can try to use "autohotkey" script to auto click on the error when it appears on screen, until a fix is found.

Comment: thanks for your solution . but i dont tink my client will accept this. :(

Answer (score 2):

If you go into `chrome://flags/` and search for "*Insecure origins treated as secure*" and then add the origin e.g. "http://example.com", you then get the tick box to allow to remember the selection.

I just tried this in Chrome 84 and MS Edge 84. You do get a warning when opening Edge that you are using an insecure option, but as it is for a specific URL this seems acceptable.

The usual caveats apply in that you do trust the site to be treated as if it was secure!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on chrome 84,

try to add in your chrome pref's file:

```
"protocol_handler":{"allowed_origin_protocol_pairs":{"SITE_DOMAIN":{"NEEDED_APP":true}}}
```

instead of:

```
"protocol_handler":{"excluded_schemes":{"NEEDED_APP":false}}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am trying to a add a local file (file:///E:) but it didn't work: {"allowed_origin_protocol_pairs":{"file:///E:":{"appurl":true}}}. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

notice that

```
"protocol_handler":{"allowed_origin_protocol_pairs":{"SITE_URL":{"APP_NAME":true}}}
```

works only with https sites

Comment: Thanks, and welcome to stackoverflow :) How can I make a one works with a local file: "file:///E:"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
"protocol_handler": {
    "allowed_origin_protocol_pairs": {
        "file://": { "myprotocol": true },
        "http://localhost:12345": { "myprotocol": true },
        "https://google.com": { "myprotocol": true },
    }
},
```

local-file/http/https are all work well.